# setting up constrained maximization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to enter the maximization problem with constraints below:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x_0, x_1}{\text{max}}
& & \Big[a(C-x)+(1-a)(z-y)\Big] \\
& \text{s.t.}
& &   a u(x_1)+(1-a)u(y)-h \geq 0 \\
& & & (a-b)(u(x)-u(y)) \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

as:

```
Maximize[{a(C-x)+(1-a)(z-y), au(x)+(1-a)u(y)-h >= 0, (a-b)(u(x)-u(z))>=0}, {x,y}]
```

Is this the correct way to enter the problem- especially the u(x) and u(y) terms?

Comment: What is $u(x)$ supposed to be, an unknown function? `Maximize[]` won't work in that case.

Comment: See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720). Also, `au` would be interpreted as a separate symbol rather than the product `a u` or `a*u`